# Cannot resolve docker-compose services hostnames on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**BUG REPORT INFORMATION**

**Description**

Cannot ping docker-compose service from within a container on Windows 10.
Pinging the IP address of that service works.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1 Create docker-compose-quick-servers.yml with the following content

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    server1:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
        container_name: Server_1
        entrypoint: ping -t localhost
      server2:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
        container_name: Server_2
        entrypoint: ping -t localhost
    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: nat
```

2 Run the docker containers: docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-quick-servers.yml up -d

3 Ping the other docker-compose service: docker exec Server_1 ping server2

**Describe the results you received:**
The ping fail. The same operation with the second service IP address works fine.

**Describe the results you expected:**
We should be able to ping services using its defined name.

**Additional information you deem important (e.g. issue happens only occasionally):**
It works fine in our prod environment (on Windows Server 2016).

Output of `docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Output of `docker info`:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 9
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.706)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.93GiB
Name: H198818
ID: HOKO:5CAS:SIQ2:SCLD:3TB7:A6GG:EH5X:763G:CBV5:UQMJ:BGSO:PF2Y
Docker Root Dir: E:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 36
 System Time: 2019-04-18T15:33:25.7898496-04:00
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

**docker inspect for both containers**
container 1

```
[
    {
        "Id": "a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280",
        "Created": "2019-07-19T15:41:58.0571535Z",
        "Path": "ping",
        "Args": [
            "-t",
            "localhost"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1180,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-07-22T13:10:28.0169558Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-07-20T03:42:53.7800119-04:00"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:cf751d69394af7dc72bd2a251b5f206c623d58ad3c227b4eb38b7f78695fd6c6",
        "ResolvConfPath": "",
        "HostnamePath": "",
        "HostsPath": "",
        "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280\\a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280-json.log",
        "Name": "/Server_2",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "windowsfilter",
        "Platform": "windows",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "nat",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 0,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "hyperv",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a187264b5df4",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "ContainerUser",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "ping",
                "-t",
                "localhost"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "be02643ae0be24af8c209ead0232c7c323bce17485989dc12dfc691d5d5ec1b6",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "temp",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "server2",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "a187264b5df41392b85a6b0d465af14e0dae699893aa2bd7d325d3638ca37280",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "nat": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "server2",
                        "a187264b5df4"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "a8c298597e4971959a217132aaf2521cdc5d0b3ce887580ad4239dce75f7e697",
                    "EndpointID": "edbb8a518b5be347f2c600864838bc850d8951a1e09a78b97f0fd0d67bf7a5d1",
                    "Gateway": "172.30.48.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.30.57.127",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:53:a2:da",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

container 2

```
[
    {
        "Id": "dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0",
        "Created": "2019-07-19T15:41:58.0571535Z",
        "Path": "ping",
        "Args": [
            "-t",
            "localhost"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1172,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-07-22T13:10:28.0179564Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-07-20T03:42:53.7730133-04:00"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:cf751d69394af7dc72bd2a251b5f206c623d58ad3c227b4eb38b7f78695fd6c6",
        "ResolvConfPath": "",
        "HostnamePath": "",
        "HostsPath": "",
        "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0\\dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0-json.log",
        "Name": "/Server_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "windowsfilter",
        "Platform": "windows",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "nat",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 0,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "hyperv",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "dca6e1b6e86c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "ContainerUser",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "ping",
                "-t",
                "localhost"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "39e91b8015a79dda2357d7e1af47455981a66b7d56d23b397d649f096e1b93f1",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "temp",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "server1",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "dca6e1b6e86c9e888f0c817c8f5677f6e9d1513ee67715b77f5ca134811ee2c0",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "nat": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "server1",
                        "dca6e1b6e86c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "a8c298597e4971959a217132aaf2521cdc5d0b3ce887580ad4239dce75f7e697",
                    "EndpointID": "8825f5c168aeb39a022de1ab4cc0f0f5bdc5a1938d490a40d476182d96904791",
                    "Gateway": "172.30.48.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.30.56.75",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:53:ad:eb",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker CE is not recommended for Windows Server. Use Docker EE Basic, it's free for Windows Servers.

Update:
In general your configuration looks ok... aliases are set, but from the ping output I see it's not a problem of pinging, but dns resolution. Second container is using some external dns to resolve server1 instead using docker internal dns.

There's a similar bug report touching docker dns resolution for windows containers: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976

This *might* be your case.

As temporary solution I'd recommend you to set up dns resolvers in containers to default docker dns at `127.0.0.11` (https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)

update 2:
I reproduced on Win1809 and it works for me:

```
PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker-compose up -d
Pulling server1 (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809)...
1809: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
58fd16eaae0b: Pull complete
Pulling server2 (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809)...
1809: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
Creating Server_1 ... done
Creating Server_2 ... done
PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0628c2fd7106        mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809   "ping -t localhost"   12 seconds ago      Up 6 seconds                            Server_1
8e52138080f2        mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809   "ping -t localhost"   12 seconds ago      Up 6 seconds                            Server_2

PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker exec Server_2 ping Server_1

Pinging Server_1 [172.27.195.21] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.27.195.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.27.195.21: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=128
PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker exec Server_1 ping Server_2

Pinging Server_2 [172.27.193.166] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.27.193.166: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.27.193.166: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker exec Server_2 ping server1

Pinging server1 [172.27.195.21] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.27.195.21: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.27.195.21: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128

PS E:\workspace\docker-test> docker exec Server_1 ping server2

Pinging server2 [172.27.193.166] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.27.193.166: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.27.193.166: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
```

Comment: That's true, however only our prod environment is a windows server, and this bug is occurring on windows 10. Also, docker compose networking documentation says it should resolve the hostname between containers running on the same host based on the service defined in the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Oh, right. Please output results from ping, nslookup and docker inspect for both containers.

Comment: ping results
`Ping request could not find host server2. Please check the name and try again.`

nslookup:
```Default Server:  dom03.hoc-cdc.ca
Address:  10.4.16.223```

Comment: And docker inspect for both containers?

Comment: edited question to include docker inspect due to long output

Comment: Edited my answer. Not much but I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, however were looking for a more permanent solution as using --dns-opt=OPTION every time we start up the container means we'd have to start some containers from a bash script instead of from the compose file.

Comment: haven't tried swarm mode due to the fact that docker compose networking documentation says it should resolve the hostname between containers running on the same host based on the service defined in the docker-compose.yml.